# Install SQL Server Driver to use Pyodbc lib in Airflow

Tags: python, sql-server, dockerfile, airflow, pyodbc

I created an airflow image inside Kubernetes and am having a hard time connecting to my SQL Server database using Pyodbc to make my Python script work.

Here's the part of DockerFile I set up:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# apt-get and system utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq \
    curl gnupg gnupg2 gnupg1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# adding custom MS repository
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN set -ex \
    && apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends build-essential \
    && export ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
    && apt-get install -yqq msodbcsql17 freetds-dev freetds-bin tdsodbc unixodbc-dev  \
    && apt-get update \
    && export ACCEPT_EULA=Y  \
    && apt-get install -yqq mssql-tools \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" \
    && apt-get install -yqq default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    && pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install -r ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/requirements.txt \
    && pip install gcloud \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,jdbc,gcp_api,mssql,mysql,kubernetes,gcp]
```

It creates the image without problems. Now I send the part of the python script that tries to connect to Sql Server:

```
import pyodbc

    database='dbd'
    uid = 'user'
    pwd = 'pass'
    server = '192.168.0.1'
    driver = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";uid=" + uid + ";pwd=" + pwd
    # MySQL Credentials and settings
    db = pyodbc.connect(driver)
    cursor = db.cursor()
```

I checked the odbcinst.ini file inside my pod and it looks like this:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

And finally the error message I have is as follows:

> ERROR - ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

What else can I do to test connectivity with SQL Server?

Comment: There's no `=` between "Driver" and "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}" in your code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: OMG! Now, change the error message: ERROR - ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can you help about the new error message?

Answer (score -1):

I found a much simpler lib to work with Airflow:

```
import pymssql

    driver = pymssql.connect(server='192.168.0.1',user='user',password='pass',database='dbd',port='1433')
    cursor = db.cursor()
```